# How to customize Google Map markers in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-maps-markers

```
markerList.forEach((marker) { 
     mapController.addMarker(marker); 
     mapController.onInfoWindowTapped.add((marker) {
          print(marker.id.toString());
     });
});
```

---

How do I call the above callback for when info-window is tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...needed to add a void callback :D